# Vue prop will pass through <router-view /> to child component 1, but not child component 2. Why?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

In App.vue I am parsing JSON data from index.html, assigning it to data "parsedUser" and sending it as prop "user". "user" passes through  to 1 of 2 child components without issue. The other component receives an empty string, Vue devtool confirms this (no errors). It receives "testProp" just fine, though. In other words, component 2 receives any prop I send it other than this particular parsed data. I understand there is perhaps a way of using vue router props via router config, and while I'm not opposed to doing that it seems that my current solution "works", at least for 1 of the 2 components, thus should work for both.

index.html:

```
<div id="app">
  {{ username|json_script:"username" }}
</div>
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <router-view :user="parsedUser" :user2="parsedUser2" :testProp="testProp"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      parsedUser: 'User not authenticated',
      parsedUser2: 'User not authenticated',
      testProp: 'User not authenticated'

    }
  },
  created() {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('username').textContent);
    this.parsedUser = parsedData;
    this.parsedUser2 = parsedData;
  },
}
</script>
```

Component 2 having the issue:

```
<template>
...
      <h1>{{ user }}{{ user2 }}{{ testProp }}</h1>
...
</template>

<script>
...
export default {
  name: 'MainComp',
   props: {
     user: String,
     user2: String,
     testProp: String
  },
 ...
</script>
```

router config:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";

import AnagramMain from "./components/Anagram/AnagramMain.vue";
import MathMain from "./components/Math/MathMain.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/math-game',
    component: MathMain
  },
  {
    path: '/anagram-game',
    component: AnagramMain
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: routes,
});

export default router;
```

- tried duplicating the context data in the index.html, and parsing it twice into two separate values.
- tried sending the parsed data ONLY to component number 2.
- tried a few other lifecycle hook options.
- double checked my router config

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. It's possibly specific to components, or data, or something else on your side. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Most times global store is used to exchange global data through the app

Comment: I'll remember to provide reproduceable problems for future posts, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue was a missing method in my django views.py. 1 of my vue app's templates could access the context data and the other could not.

Comment: Hi, this is not an answer. Please do not use answers for comments, read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you!